# Ourselves or Us

Tags: grammar

> This is subject to a certificate being forwarded to ourselves

Or

> This is subject to a certificate being forwarded to us

Answer (score 2):

It depends on who is doing the forwarding. The pronoun suffixes "self" and "selves" are used when the object is the same as the subject, e.g.

> This is subject to a certificate being forwarded by us to ourselves.

but

> This is subject to a certificate being forwarded by the customer to us.

Answer (score 1):

The reflexive (like themselves, ourselves, himself) is safe to use when it refers to an already stated noun, usually the subject of the sentence.

In this case, since the subject of the sentence is "This", the better sentence would be:

> This is subject to a certificate being forwarded to us.

However, had this sentence started with "We", then "ourselves" would have been appropriate. E.g., "We would need the certificate for ourselves."